# SPARQL propertyPath true "or" possible?

Tags: sparql, propertypath

In SPARQL propertyPath "alternative", is it possible to represent an XOR match?
Is it possible to represent a propertyPath which matches the first path OR the second path *ONLY IF* the first path doesn't exist?  I have been unable to come up with a simple propertyPath syntax that does this.

Comment: I think you can't only with property path, you need another OR in a filter.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov can you provide a simple example?

Comment: what Ivo is saying, there is no dedicated operator in the the property path syntax itself - but you can always use `or` and `negation` to construct `xor`, e.g. `filter( (exists{?s PP1 ?t} && !exists{?s PP2 ?t}) || (!exists{?s PP1 ?t} && exists{?s PP2 ?t})) )` - clearly, performance can be bad (but that's more or less often the case with SPARQL property paths, never been the fastest feature of SPARQL 1.1). Indeed you can also apply de Morgan and rewrite the logical expression, could also use `MINUS` then, `?s (PP1|PP2) ?t . MINUS {?s PP1 ?t . ?s PP2 ?t .}`